# Why does Android Studio split activity layouts into activity and content?

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I make an activity, Android studio creates two xml files. If I name it main, I get activity_main.xml and content_main.xml.  What is the advantage of doing this?  And what should I put in activity_main vs content_main?

Comment: What kind of Activity are you choosing in the wizard?

Comment: It's just a nice way to separate things. You'll see that in activity_main there is CoordinatorLayout and all the appbar/toolbar stuff. That alone takes more than half the screen in height. And you put your actual content in content_man to keep content separate from toolbar/appbar. It makes sense when you've a lot of stuff going on in the xml; otherwise, you should just go ahead and put them in one file. Also, it's not a requirement that you do this separation.

Answer (score 1):

The content.xml file gets included into the activity's xml file, so for one its reusable in multiple activities or fragments also you can manage your concerns better in smaller units which is also a good thing.